# Problem while trying to edit SharePoint workflows in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, error, sharepoint-designer-workflow

While trying to edit workflows in SharePoint designer 2013, I get this error:

> insert a stage by using the stage button on the ribbon

Is there any solution to resolve this error? I tried reinstalling SharePoint designer 2013.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting this error? while editing and adding any specific action to your workflow?

Comment: Hello @GaneshSanap: I get this error after clicking on 'Edit workflow'. I have added the screenshots now.